# Sharing provisional iPhone apps with team

Tags: iphone, provisioning, sharing

How can I take a compiled iPhone application and share it with other (non dev) team members?

Our project manager would like to be able to use/test it. I recall in the past doing this, however, I was only on the downloading end.

I am using Titanium Appcelerator, which compiles the application and adds it to iTunes to be pushed to the device. Is there a way to export this file to disk to serve to the rest of the team?

The team all has their devices added to the provisional profile.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be straight forward, not as obvious when interfacing with Titanium Appcelerator.

Open the project from Xcode
- you can access this prepared project in the build directory generated by TI Appcelerator

In Xcode, select Product>Archive

In Xcode, select Window>Organizer, navigate to Archives
- if nothing appears, you may have to edit your scheme for release/debug archives to be revealed

In Xcode Organizer>Archives, select the archive and share it

This will generate the IPA file to be served to testers.

An in depth doc by apple explains the process and steps involved.

[Distributing Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH10-SW10)